# Is there a pan flute type with fipples?

Tags: practice, performing

Has there ever been a pan flute with [Fipples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fipple)? If so what is this called?

[image]

If not, what might be the easiest way to [create](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=psqxDWUe) such an instrument?

NOTE: I asked in **[chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15982793#15982793)** if this question was appropriate and was encouraged to ask.  It doesn't follow the guidelines exactly but isn't a specifically narrow topic either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hind Ocarina makes a mouth organ that might be what you are looking for. It is similar to a panpipe in appearance, but it is basically a series of whistles in a panpipe-like arrangement.

http://hindocarina.com/ocarinas/index.php?l=product_list&c=65

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for, since it isn't played quite the same way, but this is essentially what a rank of organ pipes is.

I have not heard of a handheld, mouth-blown version of these, but I'd expect them to be more difficult to play (or at least slower) because of the need to stick the fipple in your mouth each time (without banging your teeth) and form a seal with the lips. Panpipes, on the other hand, can just be slid across the lips rather quickly. But I see no reason such an instrument couldn't be made.

**Edit:** I just found an example online of an instrument-builder who made [one such device](http://home.ica.net/~kbudd/magic.htm). It was specifically constructed for a production of Mozart's *The Magic Flute*, in which one of the singers is required to play a set of panpipes (which is usually mimed, while the orchestra flutist plays).

Comment: +1 for finding that link! I think there may be toy panpipes constructed like this too, for instance: http://www.partydelights.co.uk/product_detail.asp?ProductID=TOYSPIPES&src=gbase&utm_source=google&utm_medium=googlebase&ci_src=18615224&ci_sku=TOYSPIPES&ci_src=18615224&ci_sku=TOYSPIPES&gclid=CKLk9Pqk7b4CFcvItAodyRQA9Q

Comment: I suppose a clever instrument builder could connect all the individual fipples into a harmonica-like series of windways to make it easier to play (but without draws, only blows).

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I am looking for.  I plan to email Kevin to see if he can recommend anyone else who can make such a device(or if he he is selling already made ones).  Pan flutes are good if you are sitting and are a well practiced musician, but for singers(especially those in a play) a "fipple" pan flute would be good for simple melodies.

Comment: If you're up for a DIY project, there are guides online for making fipple flutes out of PVC piping. You wouldn't even have to worry about the tricky question of hole placement and sizing.

Comment: My kids have one of these in their bath tub: http://www.amazon.com/ALEX%C2%AE-Toys-Bathtime-Water-Flutes/dp/B000I7ZHO4 (see http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51X8fUs7kPL.jpg). It's hard to get the hand of playing it!

Comment: @Gabe Is that because of the design of the product or truly because it is more difficult to play then a traditional pan flute?  I figured/hoped the fipples would make it easier.

Comment: @CalebHines I am looking at several different DIY guides online.  The fipple placement and design is probably the only hard part.  With a [hertz meter](http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html) and some luck, I believe this is the [easiest fipple to construct](http://www.oocities.org/tpe123/folkurban/flute/homedespot.html).

Comment: @LiamWilliam: It's hard to play because you have to take your mouth off one flute and move it to another to play a different note. This takes a bit of time so you have to play at a tempo where the delay between notes seems natural.

Comment: The instrument linked in @Karen's answer seems to use a more harmonica-like mouthpiece (as I suggested), so it would probably mitigate this issue somewhat.